# How can I easily style a range of CSS classes ( ._15, ._16, ._17 ...... ._37)?

Tags: html, css, range

Simple and fast:

---

HTML + CSS (no js) - code work 100% but 1 thing:

```
<!-- ***** HTML CODE ***** -->
<!-- (more) -->
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_154" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_155" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_156" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_157" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_158" ></img>
<!-- (more) -->


/* ***** CSS code ***** */
._114,
._358
{
   left: 50px;
}
```

I need to access a *range of classes*, like this: [._114 To ._358].

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: I don't think classes starting with numbers are valid...

Comment: Its right below your post, right above these comments, right next to your name :) Also, I dont know what you are expecting here, there is no `range` for class names, you will have to list them all (usually you could do this with something like a SASS or LESS `@for` loop to run through them, though this seems excessive because its one rule that the same everywhere. Here is where sharing _one_ class with a good name becomes very viable.)

Comment: you can use a container surrounding your images and using `nth-child(n + 0)` but you have to list all rules.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch can you give a code workly 100% please?

Comment: @MC you code didn't work until you change your class name

Comment: MG, you _can_ modify the question you asked. If you can post a comment to your own question, you are logged in enough to modify it. There is an 'edit' button _right below the tags at the bottom of your post_.

Comment: @M.C. Who does this image help? What is your issue with this site? There _is_ an edit button because _its your own question_. Please try to be clearer in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: CSS does not have a *range selector*. You will have to list all classes manually or generate them using some preprocessor like SASS, Stylus or Less.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more class to your images:

```
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_154 some-img" />
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_155 some-img" />
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_156 some-img" />
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_157 some-img" />
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_158 some-img" />
```

```
.some-img {
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming these images are generated from a backend, and giving them a specific class is a *load* of work, especially if you wish to not give *every* `<img>` this class, but merely the range. You could use JavaScript for that though, but that would severly impact the performance of your page. Anyway, OP should solve this stuff in the backend using this solution.

Comment: @Roberrrt, ok, wrap them into a div with class and style all images inside of the div. And there is nothing about backend in the question. Backend part can be fixed too.

Comment: It can, and frankly, it seriously should- but that's indeed not OP's question.

Comment: @Roberrrt, so what is the question? How to write a couple hundreds of css selectors without writing each of them by hand? Isn't it a XY-problem?

Comment: *Is there a range selector in CSS?* like: `.class + $[1 to 500] { left: 50px; }` which is a pseudo mix of non-existant JS & CSS. But the answer to that question is: no.

Comment: @Roberrrt, but _no_ is usually usless unless you show the correct way to archive the result.

Comment: @Roberrrt In all fairness, this question has been modified heavily after posting. The question was not clear initially.

Comment: Yes, but the correct way isn't always possible or suits the situation.

Comment: @Qwertiy thanks but your code is not indicated. as it manages the properties of all the src group.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the element as  ._155,._156 etc
I'm added an example below

```css
._154,._155,._156,._157,._158,._159{
  border :2px solid green;
}

in the below snippet I'm applied border property to all elements.
```

```html
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_154" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_155" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_156" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_157" ></img>
<img src="img/sample.jpg" class="_158" ></img>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `mi EDIT MODE`? You seem very unclear on what you are trying to accomplish and what you are using.

Comment: @M.C. Who does this image help? Its the same as your code above, and we already explained that classes can not start with numbers in their name. And as this poster explains, they cannot start with `-` or `_` and then be followed by a number either.

Comment: @M.C. yeah..!!you can followed by any numbers of "numbers",but can't start as the  first letter.

Comment: @dreamhunter Did this just resolve his problem? What a confusing dude... Still not sure what the issue actually was...

Comment: changed code posted, now it's correct. and it's extacly like work 100% on my pc. Now since I have changed the wrong code with that working, the problem remains the access in rage-mode. P.S: SORRY for don't see the EDIT button (never used before)

Comment: This is a XY answer, which doesn't answer OP's point, but makes a valid remark about the way OP is structuring his code.

Comment: Yes, but his initial question has always been: "How can I access a range of classes", not "Why isn't my code working or HTML5 valid?"

Comment: we can get back on the real issue of the question I asked in Main Title? instead of dwelling somewhere else please?

Comment: @M.C. People are trying to help you, your main question wasn't especially clear to begin with. Don't criticise a valid answer after you change the problem slightly (your original code _did_ have this issue - and it _is_ a valid issue).

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your goal by using reverse selector but in a tricky way and that with the use of the `:not` and `nth-child selectors`

in this example i'm trying to set background color to red for the divs in range of 4 to 7

```css
/* in this example i'm trying to set the background color to red for all div that are positionned from min=4 to max=7 */


/* so to do that we need to set the default background color to red for all divs */

.parent div {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* and then we set the background color to the original default value (black) for all divs that are positionned out of range (1 to 3 and 8 to 10)) */

.parent div:not(:nth-child(-n+7)),
.parent div:not(:nth-child(n+4)) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nrdhyaj3/)

Answer (score 0):

No, not with pure CSS, that would require something like this:

```
._1, ._2, ._3, ._4, ._5, ._6, ._7, ._8, ._9, ._10, ._11, ._12, ._13, ._14, ._15, ._16, ._17, ._18, ._19, ._20 {
    left: 50px;
}
```

Thank god, we have a [SCSS alternative](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) in the form of a `@for` loop.

```
$class-slug: _ !default;

@for $i from 114 through 358 {
  .#{$class-slug}#{$i} {
    left: 50px;
     position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Which emits:

```
._114 {
    left: 50px;
}

._115 {
    left: 50px;
}

// etc etc
```

Comment: SASS is more intelligent here than you're assuming. It will automatically combine selectors which are applying the exact same set of rules.

Comment: _"in the form of a @for loop"_ it would've been better if we didn't.

Comment: @Qwertiy I very, very much agree OP is trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Comment: You have syntactical errors in your SASS code. It has to be `.#{$class-slug}#{$i}` and the semi-colon `;` must be omitted. Also, the first line you need to replace `_` by `for`.

Comment: Should be fixed now, as updated in http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/BQrKMK

Comment: Why is this down voted though? This would solve the problem in an easy way. Its either this or manually typing it in.

Comment: *shrugs* I suppose people think it's not a valid answer / contribution. Happens from time to time

Comment: :D SASS it's very nice solution, but in pure CSS it would be better!

Comment: anyway thanks for the time. a major doubt is resolved. I am satisfied. :)

Comment: @M.C. There is sadly enough no _pure_ CSS solution. The thing is though, SASS outputs _pure_ CSS, making the cumbersome listing much easier. Since you are writing this by hand you might want to consider SASS anyhow as there's a lot more workflow improvements available with it!

Comment: @somethinghere in fact with 750 images objects that I have, I wanted to avoid just to manage all access keys ".", but I believe that with this solution I can solve my problem. Although i'll have to add a piece of JS for group editing.